# Connection/Response timeout values don't seem to take effect in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am getting 'Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect' for some HTTP requests so I tried to set the connection/response timeout value to 2 minutes (which is more than the connect time required for failing HTTP requests). To do this, I updated "HTTP Request Defaults" and added 120000 as Connect and Response Timeouts.

#### HTTP Request Defaults timeouts

[[image: HTTP Request Defaults timeouts[1]]

However, when I run the test again, the HTTP requests still gave the same error. The sample result is as follows -

```
Load time: 21007
Connect Time: 21007
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 2212
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2212
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect
```

It looks like the timeout value I set in HTTP request Defaults is not getting used here. I also tried to set the value of httpclient.timeout=120000 in jmeter.properties but no change. Have I missed something?

Can somebody please help me with this?

Thanks.

Edit - I have multiple HTTP requests and each run, different requests time-out. Here is one of the HTTP requests -
[image: HTTP Request Sampler]

Updates:

I tried changing the Timeouts values in HTTP Request Defaults to very low (2000) to see how HTTP requests work. In this case, I was  getting different error for requests exceeding connection time of 2000ms -

Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException/Non HTTP response message: : failed to respond

So I think changing the timeout values is not affecting my original error -

Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException/Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect

What is the difference between these two message?

Comment: Can you show your HTTP Request configuration ?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK, here is the HTTP request configuration -

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems more of a `server configuration of connection timeout` than `client side configuration of connection timeout`, though both must be configured appropriately.

Default `connectionTimeout` in tomcat server is `20 seconds`. and you request is failed due to connection timeout at `21 seconds`. so, though you configured at client side (120000) you must configure appropriately at server side as well, otherwise, server forces to close the connection attempt and raises `Connect Timeout` exception.

Reference:

1. [The HTTP Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)  (refer `connectionTimeout` attribute)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We are using IIS server and it has connection timeout set to 2 minutes. So not sure where is this limit of 20 seconds coming from

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have faced the same problem and found that it is the default configuration in my OS (Windows). Check the following links for details:

[Where does the socket timeout of 21000 ms come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896414/where-does-the-socket-timeout-of-21000-ms-come-from/)

[Which is the default TCP connect timeout in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/193160/which-is-the-default-tcp-connect-timeout-in-windows)

Shortly, based on articles mentioned in the links above, Windows uses 3000ms initial timeout (`InitialRto` setting) and does 2 retries with doubled timeout from the previous attempt (`MaxSynRetransmissions` setting): `3sec + 2*3sec + 4*3sec = 21 sec`.
In order to increase this timeout you can set more retries with the following command:

`netsh interface tcp set global MaxSynRetransmissions=3`