# JMeter HTTP Request failed

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing

I'm really new to JMeter. I'm trying to make a simple test as I saw in some videos. When I try to run simple test it gives me an error in results tree. It says: Response code: Non HTTP response code. 
I saw a lot of things on stackoverflow, but nothing with the error I have.
Really sorry if it is a duplicate question, but I didn't found any solution for my case.

Here is what I'm trying to do: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: You dont have a header manager under your request? Try to record the google url from your browser with the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please do not point performance testing tools at sites you do not own, manage or control OR have permission from those that do have those roles. Your GOOGLE end user agreement especially forbids the use of automated tools on its interface, with the only supported interfaces for automation the published web services APIs.

Performance Testing tools are the equivalent of tactical nuclear software.  They are designed to place maximum stress on the target, up to and including destroying it's ability to continue operation. Pointing any tool of this type at a site you down't own or have permission to target is no different than throwing bombs at random houses from the back of a pickup driving through a neighborhood. I haven't been through the Jmeter license recently, but all commercial performance testing tools ban this activity under license.

Download a GNU application, install it yourself and then test that. May I recommend SugarCRM

Comment: Maybe it is because I've made it at work where we have restricted access to websites ? But I have access to google.com

Comment: There is an ethical issue here.  When you agree to use a site, including the restrictions, you should honor them.  This is also true of the tools you use - there are many license restrictions I dislike, but i strictly adhere to them.  Why would anyone accept test results from a tester with a willingness to violate licenses and agreements?   In my own organization such a tester would no longer be allowed to work in the role.

You are placing someone else's work under load without their permission.  Bad Magic.

Answer (score 3):

You [should not be load testing web sites you don't own without explicit permissions of these website owners](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)

So my expectation is that:

1. You should stop sending requests to google.com. Consider using either your own web application or sites which are designed for this form of practice like http://blazedemo.com/ or http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/. If the tutorial you're referring to assumes real life websites - I wouldn't trust this tutorial a lot.
2. You're being blocked either on Google side or on your [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) side or on your [router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) / [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) which may have automated fraudulent behaviour detection and prevention logic

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration works for me. Please try the server adress **www**.google.com. 
When calling google.com there are two requests made:

1. The first request "GET http://google.com/" returns HTTP 301 Moved Permanently. [First Request when calling google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWyTH.png)
2. The following request "GET http://www.google.com/" returns a HTTP 200 [Second Request when calling google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBNpG.png)

When you call www.google.com the 301 will not be returned:
[Request with www result in only one request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msMUL.png)

Make sure, that you network connection is ok.

Comment: Maybe it is because I've made it at work where we have restricted access to websites ? But I have access to google.com

Comment: Then it might be a proxy issue. Please use the script recorder https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the response message you may notice the cause of the error: "Connection timed out: Connect".

Your connect time is close to 21 seconds and then you receive a timeout.
This is a default TCP connection timeout (see [Where does the socket timeout of 21000 ms come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896414/where-does-the-socket-timeout-of-21000-ms-come-from/)).

I would suggest to check the network connection to the host where you run JMeter.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through the sampler result tab of the images. I guess this is not an issue with your Jmeter configuration. If you look at the sampler results it looks like this.

```
Load time: 21074
Connect Time: 21074
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 2723
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2723
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: 
Response message: Non HTTP response message:  google.com:80 ... connection timeout


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

If you look at the **Load time** and the **Connection time** they are more than **27 seconds** and both have the same value. Then the **Sent bytes** value and the **Headers size in bytes** is **0**. The **Response message** says it's a **connection time out**

Looking at those results it looks like Jmeter tried make the connection for 27 seconds and then timed out with out sending any request. That's why the sent bytes value is 0.

Since the response says connect to **google.com:80** I suspect this is due to a proxy issue or probably due to a slow connection issue.

As a solution first check if your proxy connection is on port 80. if so try to remove proxy and run the test again. If not check the net work connection speed. your script have no issues.

Good luck